# How to order posts by date - pulling post ID from wp_query and custom field

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I'm using the Custom Field Suite plugin to add posts to my page. On my page, using the code below, the posts are displayed alphabetically by title (that's because in the widget in the page editor, they are ordered alphabetically by default, but they can also be moved around manually).

However, I want them displayed by date published.

Here is the Custom Field Suite field type I'm using: http://customfieldsuite.com/field-types/relationship.html

My code

```
// The Query
$archive = CFS()->get('archive'); //getting posts from widget

foreach ( $archive as $post_id ) {
    $the_post1 = get_post( $post_id );
    $the_post = $the_post1->ID;

$the_query2 = new WP_Query( array(
'p' => $the_post,
'orderby' => 'date', //this isn't working
'order' => 'ASC'
));

// The Loop
if ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query2->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you have this code `'p' => $the_post,` on line 9. It looks like it does not belong there.

Comment: I found it here, in the first example: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Comment: based on the document you linked the `p` parameter is passed only when you wish to retrieve info about 1 specific item not multiple. I stand by what I said, that is part of the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all ID's inside an array then search for them in your WP_Query, and you can save yourself some space without declaring $the_post1 and $the_post, since you already got your post id.

```
$archive = CFS()->get('archive'); //getting posts from widget

$posts = new array();

foreach ( $archive as $post_id ) {
    array_push($posts, $post_id);
}

$the_query2 = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post__in' => $posts,
    'orderby' => 'date', //this isn't working
    'order' => 'ASC'
));

// The Loop
if ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query2->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

For future WP_Query Rerefence: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Array' (T_ARRAY) . When I delete $posts = new Array();, it goes away and everything seems to be working.

Comment: It was new array(); sorry not uppercase, just fixed it.